# Python - Exception gives 'Connection aborted' - how can I skip it and continue

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

So basically i'm using requests where I sometimes enter a URL and gives me an error saying:

```
('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

which is fine when I do a new requests again or with sleep which I do like this now:

```
 except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
        randomtime = random.randint(1,5)
        logger.warn('ERROR - Retrying again website %s, retrying in %d secs' % (url, randomtime))
        time.sleep(randomtime)
        continue
```

and what I want to do is that whenever this error comes again as ERROR - I just want to basically 'skip' it meaning that it shouldn't give me a print of it but if there comes another error that is **NOT**

```
('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

then it should print the error.

*What do I need to do to make it print other errors but just continue with the Connection aborted without printing it?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch the RemoteDisconnected exception with:

```
try:
    #your code here
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(e)
    randomtime = random.randint(1,5)
    logger.warn('ERROR - Retrying again website %s, retrying in %d secs' % (url, randomtime))
    time.sleep(randomtime)
    continue
```

Although be careful about catching exceptions quietly, it may cause you problems later by stopping you identify the true cause of an issue.

Comment: Oh you are right but a question. in your `except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:` Does it need to be *as e* at the end?

Comment: It doesn't have to be 'e' it can be something else like 'err'.  In this case where you aren't doing anything with the captured error you can remove 'as e'

Comment: Im gonna try this method, I tried the above one that I marked as correct which did skip the method even thought it was a caught of it with printing. However I do hope this method will work!

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
if str(e) != 'Connection aborted.' :
    logger.error(e)
```

However, connection can be aborted because of many different reasons, and you may want to add additional checks into the `if` statement, checking `e.reason` or other available fields.

Answer (score 2):

You should except RemoteDisconected separately from other exceptions:

```
from http.client import RemoteDisconnected    
try:
   ...
except RemoteDisconnected:
    continue
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(e)
    randomtime = random.randint(1,5)
    logger.warn('ERROR - Retrying again website %s, retrying in %d secs' % (url, randomtime))
    time.sleep(randomtime)
    continue
```

Comment: whats the difference between http.client and requests exceptions since I saw you changed it?

Comment: initially, i wrote it as requests module exception out of my mind, but then i doublechecked that requests do not have that exception. It instead comes from an underlying http.client, which is a lower level library under requests module. I should have mentioned that it in the edit notes, my bad.

Comment: Hmm I think im getting an error saying `NameError: name 'http' is not defined`

Comment: I assume I need `import http.client`

Comment: @CDNthe2nd you are correct, i updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Maybe just a rookie question but does it matter if i just have import http.client or ?

Comment: you have to import `http.client` if you want to catch this specific exception. Note that the `RemoteDisconnected` error is a child class of the `ConnectionError` as per @phil's answer, so you can safely catch the `ConnectionError` instead. The `ConnectionError`, however, is a more general exception and might produce unwanted side effects (as in passing other connection-related exception that you might want to except).

Comment: Well, I just tried the code you had and I have to say that I still getting the error from exception and it skips the RemoteDisconnect.